# What do you call an object that goes in a "slot"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call something that goes into a slot?

"Slot" here would be (according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slot)):

> A narrow depression, perforation, or aperture; especially, one for the reception of a piece fitting or sliding in it.

Edit for context:

I'm using the concepts in a software program I'm trying to write. In order to help the end users understand the end result, I came up with the physical representation of wooden boxes with an open top, called slots, with corresponding objects to go in these slots on a one-to-one basis. There would be many objects available per slot, but each object would only fit in one slot at a time

Comment: **Tab** According to those assembly directions we get from the Far East: Insert tab A into slot B.

Comment: @GEdgar: lol, I agree, although Tab is too commonly a used term for what I would like.

Comment: I am not aware of any particular "thing" that is the counterpart to _slot_. Do you have a particular type of slot in mind?

Comment: I'm using the concepts in a software program I'm trying to write. In order to help the end users understand the end result, I came up with the physical representation of wooden boxes with an open top, called slots, with corresponding objects to go in these slots on a one-to-one basis. There would be many objects available per slot, but each object would only fit in one slot at a time.

Comment: Sounds more like you're talking about (the proverbial round and square) pegs and holes. Perhaps if you consider something other than "slot" you'll find a a peg that is a better fit for your hole.

Comment: Sounds like a shape sorter.  What if you used a generic thingamajig word, like *widget*?

Comment: @mickeyf: I would be up for changing the "slot" idea, but it should probably stay in comments, so that I'm not changing the original question.

Comment: @Kit: Yes, a widget or gizmo is a good idea, and I may end up using it. I would prefer, however, to have a more direct corresponding word, which for slot appears to be rather difficult!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A key, or a token, depending on the context.

With the word key, I was referring to part of a machine component that is specially shaped to slot into, and lock with, the *keyway* of a shaft.

(Though, of course, a *key* more commonly refers to an object that slides in through the keyhole of a lock, and acts to unlock it.)

A token would be something similar to a coin, which would pass straight though a slot.

Comment: I like token, although technically what I'm going for is more of what you defined as a key. I don't want to use key, however, since it's being used already. I'll accept in a few hours if no other ideas show up.

Comment: If you want the most specific part, it's the [blade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_%28lock%29) of the key that's inserted into the slot.

Comment: @Kit: That's a bit too specific for what I was thinking. =P

Comment: @TorelTwiddle: Locating pegs/stubs and alignment pins can also fit into slots. Can you provide detail on what exactly it is that you need to describe?

Comment: I'll update the original question with my comment in the questions comments.

Comment: The word that came to my mind was "peg", but "key" works too.

Answer (score 5):

In engineering it would be a **tang**

Comment: Interesting — I’d never come across this sense of *tang* before!  Can you give some typical examples?

Comment: The tang of a knife is the part of the metal, continuous with the blade, which is fixed within the handle.

Comment: Oh, right! My husband (an electrician) has used that word before.  It's similar to a *stab*.

Answer (score 3):

*Insert* is a noun that might fit you (as for example in: *shoe insert*)

Answer (score 0):

The Qt C++ library from Nokia has the concept of slots. The counterpart to those are signals.
Signals can be connected to slots and would indicate some form of communication, e.g. a button being pressed creates a signal that reaches a slot in order to perform some action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a programmer myself, so let me give some suggestions from a computer science prospective.

A common generic term for a member of a collection of items is an *element*.  Alternatively, if your collection is accessed by arbitrary *key*, e.g. a "hash table", "map", "associative array" or "dictionary", you might use the more specific term *value* (part of a *key/value pair*, or *entry*).

Also note that the specific term *slot* is often used academically when discussing the classic "hash table" data structure; this may be confusing to other programmers if your data structure behaviors differently.  I realize you're more looking for a term for end-users, but it's important to be clear to other coders as well.